# Difficulty using Xpath/CSS when scraping

Tags: python, css, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape this website:

https://www.coolblue.nl/en/our-assortment

I am collecting the list of all URLs for product categories. I can get almost all of them. For some reason, those "More.." tabs are being really difficult to get.

I believe it has something to do with my selectors. At this point I'm trying to get those specific "More.." URLs in the shell, just to figure out how to correctly select them. For example, in the "Laptops, desktops and monitors" section, the "More.." category has href="/en/laptops-desktops-monitors". It comes after the "Monitors" category, with href="/en/monitors".

Here is what im trying to do.

I open a scrapy shell:

```
scrapy shell https://www.coolblue.nl/en/our-assortment
```

and then i try to select what i want by index. I tried both Xpath and CSS, in different ways:

```
>>> response.xpath("//a[@class='category-navigation--link']/@href")[3].getall()
['/en/monitors']
>>> response.xpath("//a[@class='category-navigation--link']/@href")[4].getall()
['/en/keyboards']

>>> response.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'category-navigation--link')]/@href")[3].getall()
['/en/monitors']
>>> response.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'category-navigation--link')]/@href")[4].getall()
['/en/keyboards']

>>> response.css("a.category-navigation--link::attr('href')")[3].getall()
['/en/monitors']
>>> response.css("a.category-navigation--link::attr('href')")[4].getall()
['/en/keyboards']
```

As you can see, it jumped from the "Monitors" category to the "Keyboards" category, and i don't know why. The 4th index should have a value '/en/laptops-desktops-monitors', which isnt anywhere else in that list, because i already searched for it.

It should show in that 4th index but it doesn't... any ideas what is going on?

Comment: For some reason the "More..." links do not always appear on that page. Clear your cache and you will see what I mean. Even the Dutch version (https://www.coolblue.nl/ons-assortiment) does not always show me the "Meer..." links. That would explain why you are getting the next link instead.

Comment: Holy smokes! Nice catch! I was already thinking i was going crazy here. I could swear just some days ago those "More.." tabs werent there in the first place. By cleaning the cache and checking in sit it is perfectly clear the link that was in those tabs is now on the sub sections! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are not able to get the `Laptops, desktops & monitors` is because that link doesn't have the class `category-navigation--link`. Use the below xpath that will retrieve both category titles and navigation links.

```
//a[@class='category-navigation--link' or parent::h3[@class='product-category-navigation__title']]/@href
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution a lot, because i know scrapy will not always see the cacheless version of the page. With this condition inside the selector i should be able to code it in a way that it deals with both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason those "More" links do not always show up in the page:
[image]

I also get this:
[image]

Note that in the one version it has "More" links, in the other version the headings are links. Whenever I clear the cache I get the second version. Scrapy also seems to get the version without the "More" links.

Instead, I would suggest you get the links from the menu (even if they appear hidden to you).

Here is how you can get the (blue) heading links in the "Computers and Tablets" menu:

```
>>> response.css('#computers-tablets .product-category-navigation__title a::attr("href")').getall()
['/en/laptops-desktops-monitors', '/en/peripherals', '/en/tablets-ereaders', '/en/computer-parts', '/en/printers-scanners', '/en/memory-storage', '/en/network-internet', '/en/gaming']
```

Here is how you can get the links under each heading:

```
>>> response.css('#computers-tablets .category-navigation--item a::attr("href")').getall()
['/en/laptops', '/en/laptops/apple-macbook', '/en/desktops', '/en/monitors', '/en/keyboards', '/en/mouses', '/en/office-supplies', '/en/tablets', '/en/tablets/apple-ipad', '/en/e-readers', '/en/tablet-covers', '/en/internal-hard-drives', '/en/internal-ssd', '/en/video-cards', '/en/ram', '/en/printers', '/en/scanners', '/en/cartridges', '/en/toners', '/en/external-hard-drives', '/en/external-ssds', '/en/memory-cards', '/en/nas', '/en/routers', '/en/powerline-adapters', '/en/network-switches', '/en/wifi-repeaters', '/en/consoles', '/en/video-games', '/en/gaming-headsets', '/en/vr-gear']
```

Comment: Thanks! All seems fine now =D